# Bash Script - For loop using find -exec cp produces error: cp: omitting directory

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, copy, find

**Background**

I have two folders of images... FOLDER ONE is the main folder with thousands of colored images. FOLDER TWO is a filtered folder of things that I've been looking for throughout FOLDER ONE, but the images in FOLDER TWO are in black and white.

*Special Note* – the file names of the images in FOLDER TWO are the same as in FOLDER ONE + some other info afterwards (but before the .jpeg extension).

**My goal**

Search FOLDER ONE for the beginning part of the name of the files in FOLDER TWO (so that I can get the colored copy of the images I've filtered), and then copy those images to another folder called PASS FOLDER.

**My code**

*note* – FOLDER ONE, TWO, PASS FOLDER = F1, F2, PASSED (respectively)

```
for doc in F2/*
do
    name=`basename $doc`;
    name=${name%-*};
    find /home/user/F1/ -name "$name*" -exec cp {} /home/user/PASSED/ \;;
done
```

**My problem**

I keep getting the error

> cp: omitting directory '/home/user/F1/'

Please help!  I think this should be very simple to do, it's just consistently having problems.  I've also tested each individual part of the for loop on its own, and they work.  I think the for loop is messing something up, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `find` is handing `cp` directories to copy and you only want to copy files.  Thus, replace:

```
find /home/user/F1/ -name "$name*" -exec cp {} /home/user/PASSED/ \;
```

With:

```
find /home/user/F1/ -type f -name "$name*" -exec cp {} /home/user/PASSED/ \;
```

Thw predicate `-type f` tells `find` to match only for regular files, not directories.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks a bunch!  I'd been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 1):

just add -r parameter. after cp

```
find /home/user/F1/ -name "$name*" -exec cp -r {} /home/user/PASSED/ \;;
```